# Where did my browser recover node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules, browserify

I'm developing a new website to get informations about movies and I use NodeJS. I handle my database with MongoDB, I have my database movies and my other database actors. Each movie has a list of actors (this list contains ID of actors). Now when I want to show a movie on my website, I need to list actors names, so I create a function for that but I want to execute this function on client side during HTML page display. So I don't even know if it's really possible but I use browserify to translate my JS server side script in JS client side script. 
But translation doesn't work. Browserify require the querystring module and then it call the unescape function fo querystring but it raise an error "qs.unespace is not a function". 
So I go in terminal and I print the querystring module, unescape function seems to exist. But if I print module source code in my firefox browser with toSource() function, it returns a different source code without unescape function.

So my question is : Where did my browser found the code? Is it really possible to do what I want?

Here is the code of querystring module on my PC

```
// Query String Utilities

'use strict';

var QueryString = exports;
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;


// a safe fast alternative to decodeURIComponent
QueryString.unescapeBuffer = function(s, decodeSpaces) {
  var out = new Buffer(s.length);
  var state = 0;
  var n, m, hexchar;

  for (var inIndex = 0, outIndex = 0; inIndex <= s.length; inIndex++) {
    var c = inIndex < s.length ? s.charCodeAt(inIndex) : NaN;
    switch (state) {
      case 0: // Any character
        switch (c) {
          case 37: // '%'
            n = 0;
            m = 0;
            state = 1;
            break;
          case 43: // '+'
            if (decodeSpaces)
              c = 32; // ' '
            // falls through
          default:
            out[outIndex++] = c;
            break;
        }
        break;

      case 1: // First hex digit
        hexchar = c;
        if (c >= 48/*0*/ && c <= 57/*9*/) {
          n = c - 48/*0*/;
        } else if (c >= 65/*A*/ && c <= 70/*F*/) {
          n = c - 65/*A*/ + 10;
        } else if (c >= 97/*a*/ && c <= 102/*f*/) {
          n = c - 97/*a*/ + 10;
        } else {
          out[outIndex++] = 37/*%*/;
          out[outIndex++] = c;
          state = 0;
          break;
        }
        state = 2;
        break;

      case 2: // Second hex digit
        state = 0;
        if (c >= 48/*0*/ && c <= 57/*9*/) {
          m = c -  48/*0*/;
        } else if (c >= 65/*A*/ && c <= 70/*F*/) {
          m = c - 65/*A*/ + 10;
        } else if (c >= 97/*a*/ && c <= 102/*f*/) {
          m = c - 97/*a*/ + 10;
        } else {
          out[outIndex++] = 37/*%*/;
          out[outIndex++] = hexchar;
          out[outIndex++] = c;
          break;
        }
        out[outIndex++] = 16 * n + m;
        break;
    }
  }

  // TODO support returning arbitrary buffers.

  return out.slice(0, outIndex - 1);
};


function qsUnescape(s, decodeSpaces) {
  try {
    return decodeURIComponent(s);
  } catch (e) {
    return QueryString.unescapeBuffer(s, decodeSpaces).toString();
  }
}
QueryString.unescape = qsUnescape;


var hexTable = new Array(256);
for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
  hexTable[i] = '%' + ((i < 16 ? '0' : '') + i.toString(16)).toUpperCase();
QueryString.escape = function(str) {
  // replaces encodeURIComponent
  // http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.4
  if (typeof str !== 'string')
    str += '';
  var out = '';
  var lastPos = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);

    // These characters do not need escaping (in order):
    // ! - . _ ~
    // ' ( ) *
    // digits
    // alpha (uppercase)
    // alpha (lowercase)
    if (c === 0x21 || c === 0x2D || c === 0x2E || c === 0x5F || c === 0x7E ||
        (c >= 0x27 && c <= 0x2A) ||
        (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) ||
        (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A) ||
        (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7A)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (i - lastPos > 0)
      out += str.slice(lastPos, i);

    // Other ASCII characters
    if (c < 0x80) {
      lastPos = i + 1;
      out += hexTable[c];
      continue;
    }

    // Multi-byte characters ...
    if (c < 0x800) {
      lastPos = i + 1;
      out += hexTable[0xC0 | (c >> 6)] + hexTable[0x80 | (c & 0x3F)];
      continue;
    }
    if (c < 0xD800 || c >= 0xE000) {
      lastPos = i + 1;
      out += hexTable[0xE0 | (c >> 12)] +
             hexTable[0x80 | ((c >> 6) & 0x3F)] +
             hexTable[0x80 | (c & 0x3F)];
      continue;
    }
    // Surrogate pair
    ++i;
    var c2;
    if (i < str.length)
      c2 = str.charCodeAt(i) & 0x3FF;
    else
      throw new URIError('URI malformed');
    lastPos = i + 1;
    c = 0x10000 + (((c & 0x3FF) << 10) | c2);
    out += hexTable[0xF0 | (c >> 18)] +
           hexTable[0x80 | ((c >> 12) & 0x3F)] +
           hexTable[0x80 | ((c >> 6) & 0x3F)] +
           hexTable[0x80 | (c & 0x3F)];
  }
  if (lastPos === 0)
    return str;
  if (lastPos < str.length)
    return out + str.slice(lastPos);
  return out;
};

var stringifyPrimitive = function(v) {
  if (typeof v === 'string')
    return v;
  if (typeof v === 'number' && isFinite(v))
    return '' + v;
  if (typeof v === 'boolean')
    return v ? 'true' : 'false';
  return '';
};


QueryString.stringify = QueryString.encode = function(obj, sep, eq, options) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';

  var encode = QueryString.escape;
  if (options && typeof options.encodeURIComponent === 'function') {
    encode = options.encodeURIComponent;
  }

  if (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object') {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var len = keys.length;
    var flast = len - 1;
    var fields = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      var k = keys[i];
      var v = obj[k];
      var ks = encode(stringifyPrimitive(k)) + eq;

      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        var vlen = v.length;
        var vlast = vlen - 1;
        for (var j = 0; j < vlen; ++j) {
          fields += ks + encode(stringifyPrimitive(v[j]));
          if (j < vlast)
            fields += sep;
        }
        if (vlen && i < flast)
          fields += sep;
      } else {
        fields += ks + encode(stringifyPrimitive(v));
        if (i < flast)
          fields += sep;
      }
    }
    return fields;
  }
  return '';
};

// Parse a key/val string.
QueryString.parse = QueryString.decode = function(qs, sep, eq, options) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';

  var obj = {};

  if (typeof qs !== 'string' || qs.length === 0) {
    return obj;
  }

  if (typeof sep !== 'string')
    sep += '';

  var eqLen = eq.length;
  var sepLen = sep.length;

  var maxKeys = 1000;
  if (options && typeof options.maxKeys === 'number') {
    maxKeys = options.maxKeys;
  }

  var pairs = Infinity;
  if (maxKeys > 0)
    pairs = maxKeys;

  var decode = QueryString.unescape;
  if (options && typeof options.decodeURIComponent === 'function') {
    decode = options.decodeURIComponent;
  }
  var customDecode = (decode !== qsUnescape);

  var keys = [];
  var lastPos = 0;
  var sepIdx = 0;
  var eqIdx = 0;
  var key = '';
  var value = '';
  var keyEncoded = customDecode;
  var valEncoded = customDecode;
  var encodeCheck = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; ++i) {
    var code = qs.charCodeAt(i);

    // Try matching key/value pair separator (e.g. '&')
    if (code === sep.charCodeAt(sepIdx)) {
      if (++sepIdx === sepLen) {
        // Key/value pair separator match!
        var end = i - sepIdx + 1;
        if (eqIdx < eqLen) {
          // If we didn't find the key/value separator, treat the substring as
          // part of the key instead of the value
          if (lastPos < end)
            key += qs.slice(lastPos, end);
        } else if (lastPos < end)
          value += qs.slice(lastPos, end);
        if (keyEncoded)
          key = decodeStr(key, decode);
        if (valEncoded)
          value = decodeStr(value, decode);
        // Use a key array lookup instead of using hasOwnProperty(), which is
        // slower
        if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          obj[key] = value;
          keys[keys.length] = key;
        } else {
          var curValue = obj[key];
          // `instanceof Array` is used instead of Array.isArray() because it
          // is ~15-20% faster with v8 4.7 and is safe to use because we are
          // using it with values being created within this function
          if (curValue instanceof Array)
            curValue[curValue.length] = value;
          else
            obj[key] = [curValue, value];
        }
        if (--pairs === 0)
          break;
        keyEncoded = valEncoded = customDecode;
        encodeCheck = 0;
        key = value = '';
        lastPos = i + 1;
        sepIdx = eqIdx = 0;
      }
      continue;
    } else {
      sepIdx = 0;
      if (!valEncoded) {
        // Try to match an (valid) encoded byte (once) to minimize unnecessary
        // calls to string decoding functions
        if (code === 37/*%*/) {
          encodeCheck = 1;
        } else if (encodeCheck > 0 &&
                   ((code >= 48/*0*/ && code <= 57/*9*/) ||
                    (code >= 65/*A*/ && code <= 70/*Z*/) ||
                    (code >= 97/*a*/ && code <= 102/*z*/))) {
          if (++encodeCheck === 3)
            valEncoded = true;
        } else {
          encodeCheck = 0;
        }
      }
    }

    // Try matching key/value separator (e.g. '=') if we haven't already
    if (eqIdx < eqLen) {
      if (code === eq.charCodeAt(eqIdx)) {
        if (++eqIdx === eqLen) {
          // Key/value separator match!
          var end = i - eqIdx + 1;
          if (lastPos < end)
            key += qs.slice(lastPos, end);
          encodeCheck = 0;
          lastPos = i + 1;
        }
        continue;
      } else {
        eqIdx = 0;
        if (!keyEncoded) {
          // Try to match an (valid) encoded byte once to minimize unnecessary
          // calls to string decoding functions
          if (code === 37/*%*/) {
            encodeCheck = 1;
          } else if (encodeCheck > 0 &&
                     ((code >= 48/*0*/ && code <= 57/*9*/) ||
                      (code >= 65/*A*/ && code <= 70/*Z*/) ||
                      (code >= 97/*a*/ && code <= 102/*z*/))) {
            if (++encodeCheck === 3)
              keyEncoded = true;
          } else {
            encodeCheck = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (code === 43/*+*/) {
      if (eqIdx < eqLen) {
        if (i - lastPos > 0)
          key += qs.slice(lastPos, i);
        key += '%20';
        keyEncoded = true;
      } else {
        if (i - lastPos > 0)
          value += qs.slice(lastPos, i);
        value += '%20';
        valEncoded = true;
      }
      lastPos = i + 1;
    }
  }

  // Check if we have leftover key or value data
  if (pairs > 0 && (lastPos < qs.length || eqIdx > 0)) {
    if (lastPos < qs.length) {
      if (eqIdx < eqLen)
        key += qs.slice(lastPos);
      else if (sepIdx < sepLen)
        value += qs.slice(lastPos);
    }
    if (keyEncoded)
      key = decodeStr(key, decode);
    if (valEncoded)
      value = decodeStr(value, decode);
    // Use a key array lookup instead of using hasOwnProperty(), which is
    // slower
    if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      obj[key] = value;
      keys[keys.length] = key;
    } else {
      var curValue = obj[key];
      // `instanceof Array` is used instead of Array.isArray() because it
      // is ~15-20% faster with v8 4.7 and is safe to use because we are
      // using it with values being created within this function
      if (curValue instanceof Array)
        curValue[curValue.length] = value;
      else
        obj[key] = [curValue, value];
    }
  }

  return obj;
};


// v8 does not optimize functions with try-catch blocks, so we isolate them here
// to minimize the damage
function decodeStr(s, decoder) {
  try {
    return decoder(s);
  } catch (e) {
    return QueryString.unescape(s, true);
  }
}
```

And this is the code returned by toSource() function in my browser :

```
qs = ({parse:(function(qs, sep, eq, options) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';
  var obj = {};

  if (typeof qs !== 'string' || qs.length === 0) {
    return obj;
  }

  var regexp = /\+/g;
  qs = qs.split(sep);

  var maxKeys = 1000;
  if (options && typeof options.maxKeys === 'number') {
    maxKeys = options.maxKeys;
  }

  var len = qs.length;
  // maxKeys <= 0 means that we should not limit keys count
  if (maxKeys > 0 && len > maxKeys) {
    len = maxKeys;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var x = qs[i].replace(regexp, '%20'),
        idx = x.indexOf(eq),
        kstr, vstr, k, v;

    if (idx >= 0) {
      kstr = x.substr(0, idx);
      vstr = x.substr(idx + 1);
    } else {
      kstr = x;
      vstr = '';
    }

    k = decodeURIComponent(kstr);
    v = decodeURIComponent(vstr);

    if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, k)) {
      obj[k] = v;
    } else if (isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].push(v);
    } else {
      obj[k] = [obj[k], v];
    }
  }

  return obj;
}), decode:(function(qs, sep, eq, options) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';
  var obj = {};

  if (typeof qs !== 'string' || qs.length === 0) {
    return obj;
  }

  var regexp = /\+/g;
  qs = qs.split(sep);

  var maxKeys = 1000;
  if (options && typeof options.maxKeys === 'number') {
    maxKeys = options.maxKeys;
  }

  var len = qs.length;
  // maxKeys <= 0 means that we should not limit keys count
  if (maxKeys > 0 && len > maxKeys) {
    len = maxKeys;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var x = qs[i].replace(regexp, '%20'),
        idx = x.indexOf(eq),
        kstr, vstr, k, v;

    if (idx >= 0) {
      kstr = x.substr(0, idx);
      vstr = x.substr(idx + 1);
    } else {
      kstr = x;
      vstr = '';
    }

    k = decodeURIComponent(kstr);
    v = decodeURIComponent(vstr);

    if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, k)) {
      obj[k] = v;
    } else if (isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].push(v);
    } else {
      obj[k] = [obj[k], v];
    }
  }

  return obj;
}), stringify:(function(obj, sep, eq, name) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';
  if (obj === null) {
    obj = undefined;
  }

  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    return map(objectKeys(obj), function(k) {
      var ks = encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(k)) + eq;
      if (isArray(obj[k])) {
        return map(obj[k], function(v) {
          return ks + encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(v));
        }).join(sep);
      } else {
        return ks + encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(obj[k]));
      }
    }).join(sep);

  }

  if (!name) return '';
  return encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(name)) + eq +
         encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(obj));
}), encode:(function(obj, sep, eq, name) {
  sep = sep || '&';
  eq = eq || '=';
  if (obj === null) {
    obj = undefined;
  }

  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    return map(objectKeys(obj), function(k) {
      var ks = encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(k)) + eq;
      if (isArray(obj[k])) {
        return map(obj[k], function(v) {
          return ks + encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(v));
        }).join(sep);
      } else {
        return ks + encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(obj[k]));
      }
    }).join(sep);

  }

  if (!name) return '';
  return encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(name)) + eq +
         encodeURIComponent(stringifyPrimitive(obj));
})})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get variables from server-side nodejs you can use ejs. It's basically html but it's dynamic and you can set values to variables. using `<% var %>` from Nodejs. To define a variable to be used by ejs use it's really simple (but you need express). Just install ejs first and rename html files to ejs. Here is the code to get started on nodejs:

```
//express modules
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

//rendering ejs
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname); //this is optional, but setting the second paramater to __dirname will make ejs load content from your workplace folder instead of expecting a /views folder

app.locals.varname = 'value' //declare global variable to be used by any file
//hosting get requests for localhost
app.get('/' /*any val is fine but setting it to will load the page on just localhost:3000*/, function(request, response){
     response.render("ejsfilename", {
        obj-name:'obj-value'/*input variables locally to this ejs file using this method*/), 
        varname);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`express server listening on ${port}`)
});
```